# Inkscape, select many paths for stroke to path

Tags: inkscape, stroke

Inkscape 0.92, with the option to upgrade to 1.01 if that contains a fix

How do I select many paths for stroke to path. I know I can <kbd>shift</kbd> select multiple paths, but I'm working towards a design that will have way too many paths to <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>click</kbd> select.

Say I have an svg file of a snowflake as generated by https://www.misha.studio/snowflaker/ that is a set of paths with a thick stroke. I'd like to select all strokes in one go to perform stroke to path. Simply selecting the object then stroke-to-path does nothing. Nor does entering the group and drag selecting multiple sub-elements, nor Select All. Using the node tool to drag then stroke-to-path doesn't work either.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I wouldn't use that online app to generate these. Something similar could be created entirely in Inkscape using rotated and reflected clones. [See example](https://imgur.com/a/lmKRbp6)

Comment: @BillyKerr, Woah, that's pretty cool, I might have to check out. I liked the website just because it creates a whole field of randomly generated that I could feed to my laser cutter. I'm also looking for a more general answer because my ultimate goal is making a cut street map and QGIS makes roads as vectors with differing stroke widths. Thanks

Comment: If you want to play with the SVG (made in Inskcape 1.0) or see how I constructed it,  I've shared it here: https://svgshare.com/i/SHH.svg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has multilevel groups which make things complex. You see them with the objects panel.

The snowflake is inside one group and the black background rectangle is inside another group.

[image]

I selected the group which contains the snowflake as an internal group and colored all strokes to red.

In the next image the black background group is deleted, the group with the snowflake is disassembled by applying extension Arrange > Deep Ungroup. All fill colors (there were some) are removed:

[image]

It also lost stroke widths and stroke end styles. A thin skeleton was left.

I put a wider stroke and rounded stroke ends. Stroke to path worked when all pieces were selected. I dragged one branch apart to show the pieces:

[image]

BTW. Stroke to path makes the shape difficult to edit, but you need it if you want to make an union and use it for ex. as a clipping path.

Comment: Doh! I always forget about looking in the objects panel to see the full structure and do the multi-select. This looks very helpful. Thanks!